# Entity Framework 4.0 non-mapped scalar property snafu

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have an imported function that returns (selects) a collection of Entities; the function however, returns an additional column that does not exist on the table.  I want to map this column (just for select operations) to the Entity object, so I created a partial class and coded the property, however, I cannot find a way to map the column in question to the property I coded in my partial class for the Entity object.  I did try to add this property via the EDMX designer, but I get the error: "property it not mapped: 11009" which makes sense.  What am I missing?

**EDIT**:
"I cannot find a way to map the column in question to the property I coded in my partial class for the Entity object"

Just to clarity: When I go to the "Function Import Mappings' for the imported function in question, the only mappings available to me are those that can be associated with columns on the table I am trying to map the return values to; because the column I want to map does not exist on the table, there is nothing to map it to.

Comment: Provide your entity and mappings.

Comment: @MystereMan - Are you saying this is possible?

Comment: I'm saying that without code, we don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @MystereMan - Not that hard; table A (A.ColA, A.ColB) maps to Entity A in EF.  I code MyColumnProperty property for Entity class using a partial class. I import a function (Select_A) that selects columns ColA, ColB, off table A AND [MyColumn] where MyColumn is NOT a column in table A.  I cannot find a way to map MyColumn returned from A.Select_A to EntityAPartialClassICoded.MyColumnProperty.  Not looking to do anything with MYColumnProperty but read it (no inserts/updates).

Comment: Is this not just about a complex type?